# Mapping information from .yml file

Tags: java, file, yaml

I'm trying to map the following configuration which is stored in an application.yml file

```
agents:
    ongo:
        mappings:
            - scopeName: email
              mapping: [mail, test1, test2, test3, test4]
            - scopeName: phoneNumber
              mapping: [phoneNumber, workPhoneNumber, personalPhoneNumber]
```

I made a class called AgentConfiguration which looks like :

```
public class AgentConfiguration {

    private Map<String, List<MyClass>> mappings;

    public Map<String, List<MyClass>> getMappings() {
        return mappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(Map<String, List<MyClass>> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    public class MyClass {
        private String scopeName;
        private List<String> mapping;

        public String getScopeName() {
            return scopeName;
        }

        public void setScopeName(String scopeName) {
            this.scopeName = scopeName;
        }

        public List<String> getMapping() {
            return mapping;
        }

        public void setMapping(List<String> mapping) {
            this.mapping = mapping;
        }
    }

}
```

So, when I run the following code : 
    AgentConfiguration agent = new AgentConfiguration();

And then I evaluate "agent.getMapptins()" it looks like :

[image]

But if I use a 
    "Map< String, Object >" 
instead of 
    "Map< String, List< MyClass > > mappings" will return the following code
[image]

So why when I'm using MyClass it doesn't bind anything from application.yml file?

Comment: Can you add the code in which you instantiate `mappings` ?

Comment: Hey @jeanr, thank you for quick reply but meanwhile I have figured out how to do it. Have a nice day !

Answer (score 0):

Ok, I have figured out how to do it.

I have changed the AgentConfiguration class :

```
public class AgentConfiguration {

    private List<MyClass> mappings;

    public List<MyClass> getMappings() {
        return mappings;
    }

    public void setMappings(List<MyClass> mappings) {
        this.mappings = mappings;
    }

    static public class MyClass{
        private String scopeName;
        private List<String> mapping;

        public AgentConfigScope() {
        }

        public String getScopeName() {
            return scopeName;
        }

        public void setScopeName(String scopeName) {
            this.scopeName = scopeName;
        }

        public List<String> getMapping() {
            return mapping;
        }

        public void setMapping(List<String> mapping) {
            this.mapping = mapping;
        }
    }
}
```

Also, keep in mind that the inner class should be static , a collegue told that is due to Spring proxy limitation ...or something like that. AOP in Spring works only on public methods.

Have a nice day!